Participle phrases as object complement
Why is the first sentence not idiomatic?


If you find this item suiting your project, please let us know.
(suiting is a participle as object complement)


We have another similar sentence with a Participle as an idiomatic
object complement.


If you find this item appealing for your upcoming event, please let
us know.



Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The verb find has many different meanings, one of which is "perceive or experience (something) to be the case". In this meaning, it's a verb of cognition such as believe.
With verbs of cognition, you can use an adjective as a predicative complement (find this item appealing as in 2). Note that appealing here is not an -ing form of the verb appeal but it's a full-fledged adjective in its own right.
By contrast, suiting in suiting your project as in 1 is not an adjective but an -ing form of a verb because it takes a direct object your project. Verbs of cognition cannot take an -ing form of a verb as a second complement after the direct object. If the second complement has to be a verb, a to-infinitive form of a verb should be used instead, as in If you find this item to suit your project, please let us know.
Note that believe behaves in a similar way.
Now, @Paul Tanenbaum says in a comment:

I find this question intriguing. And all the more so because a seemingly trivial change to the question, substituting an for this, creates a perfectly acceptable sentence. In that different sentence, suiting means “that suits” or “[that is] suited to.”

1'. If you find an item suiting your project, please let us know.
Here, an item suiting your project forms a noun phrase (NP), and find takes the NP as the direct object. So it's not a verb of cognition. Hence the perfectly acceptable sentence.

In the second example, does "find" function as a transitive verb which takes an object "this project" Then why do you say a predicative complement? Rather,  is 'appealing for your upcoming event"  the object complement? Could you list another example? As far as I know 'find' never functions as a link (copula) to take predicative complements.

If you find an item suits or fits your project. How can it be suiting?

@A_Mendes Your first sentence: In the second example, does "find" function as a transitive verb which takes an object "this project". But the second example doesn't even have this project. Only the first example has your project.// Then why do you say a predicative complement? Rather, is 'appealing for your upcoming event" the object complement? Subject and object complements in traditional grammar are called subjective and objective predicative complements, respectively in H&P's CGEL. You can simply ignore "predicative" if you follow traditional grammar.

Explanations on the basis of OALD  and CoGEL
If  the meaning of "find" in this sentence falls under the category "BY EXPERIENCE/TESTING" (to discover that something is true after you have tried it tested it or experienced it), as it seems to be the desired  sense, then the sentence is not idiomatic; (Incidentally, this meaning contradicts the would-be fact that "find" should be a cognitive verb since "discover" is an active verb, that is  the opposite of a cognitive verb (Semantics of Mental Verbs in English), see preceding answer.); in this category only the following constructions are possible.

[V (that)], [VN- ADJ], [VN to inf,VN that], [VN-N]

Only the following forms of the sentence are then correct.


[V (that)] If you find (that) this item suits your project, please let us know.
[VN- ADJ] If you find this item suitable to your project, …
[VN to inf,[…] If this item is found to be suitable to your project, … (passive voice)
[[…],VN that] If it is found that this item is suitable to your project, … (impersonal "it", prop "it", dummy "it", "that" never omitted)
[VN-N] If you find this item a good contribution to your project, … (There is no corresponding noun, and the meaning has to be changed a bit so as to use the construction while saying approximetely the same thing; merely included for the sake of completeness and to show as well that a quite perfect fit is, more often than not, impossible.)


However, if the context made for the sense "IN AN UNEXPECTED SITUATION to discover sb/sth/yourself doing sth or in a particular situation, especially when this is unexpected" (OALD), then the sentence is not idiomatic, but only because of the semantics. This sense is the one to be understood in certain cases proposed in the comments. Unlike the other acceptation, this one comprises the possibility of the construction "[VN-ing]". However, certain verbs fit that context better than others; "to suit" expresses a state that might  suddenly be acknowledged, but it is not such a typical verb, the usual verbs being verbs of doing ("they found them smoking in the yard", "she found the dog tearing up a cushion in the kitchen", "he found her sleeping in her chair", etc). This is perhaps why the given sense of the verb in combination with the -ing form does not spring to mind easily, and indeed not at all (nonsense).)
About certain comments that have been made
RE "We found Sarah sleeping. ( I believe sleeping is not a real adjective)." and "I found her talking to her boyfriend": "Find" is not quite the same verb in this sentence;  the meaning is, as said above, "IN AN UNEXPECTED SITUATION to discover sb/sth/yourself doing sth …" (OALD).
RE "I find this question intriguing. And all the more so because a seemingly trivial change to the question, substituting "an" for "this", creates a perfectly acceptable sentence. In that different sentence, "suiting" means “that suits” or “[that is] suited to.”"

If you find an item suiting your project, please let us know.

What makes the sentence perfect is not the change in the determiner only; it is the change in the determiner coupled to a subjective change in the meaning of the verb. The verb is now different ; it has either one of three meanings, "to discover BY CHANCE, BY SEARCHING, BY STUDYING/THINKING"; in these three categories the construction "[VN]" is allowed, and this construction corresponds to "If you find an/the item suiting your project" (true also for "the") where "suiting your project" is now naturally acknowledged as a postmodifier of "item". The use of the demonstrative "this" does not preclude this possibility.

If you find this/the  item suiting your project, please let us know. (There is a particular item that has been mislaid or not yet fully identified and it has the quality of suiting the project; in this case "the" would be used more often in place of "this".)

